# Office Communicator Tabbed IMs? Windows Tab Utility?

Tags: windows-vista, tabs, instant-messaging, ms-office-communicator

Is there a way to get Office Communicator + Tabbed IM windows? Either something directly supported by Microsoft or a third party utility that will aggregate windows into tabs that belong to the same application?

FWIW, I'm using office communicator 2007

Comment: Good question, it just highlights the lacks of accessibility on an IM designed in Redmond. Now, is there a solution for their Mac version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found these utilities for providing tabbing to applications

- [WinTabber](http://www.wintabber.com/)
- [WindowTabs](http://www.windowtabs.com/)

**EDIT**

Ending up purchasing [WindowTabs](http://www.windowtabs.com/). It is working quite well. =)